# Semaphores in Java. Why second thread is not waiting?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I have one static Semaphore instance.

```
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
```

Now I have two Threads (Sending Thread and Receiving Thread)

Sending Thread:

```
public class SendingThread implements Runnable {

    private Semaphore semaphore;

    public SendingThread(Semaphore semaphore){
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("1");
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            this.semaphore.acquire();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

and receiving Thread:

```
public class RecievingThread implements Runnable {

    private Semaphore semaphore;

    public RecievingThread(Semaphore semaphore){
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("2");
         this.semaphore.release();
            System.out.println("3");
    }
}
```

When I start this 2 threads according to my understanding Receiving Thread will **wait** for 4 second till
Sending Thread will **notify**  it that Receiving Thread can continue. It means that  `System.out.println("3");` will be printed with 4 second delay, but when I run this code all three values are printed immediately. Why?

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `new Semaphore(1)` has **1 initial permit** and thus allows for one immediate `acquire` to go through. Furthermore since a `release` is *always* allowed both threads proceeds immediately.

To force one thing to happen before the other, you can use `new Semaphore(0)`. This will force the thread calling `acquire` to *wait* for the thread executing `release`.

Comment: Thank you. I need to switch between acquire and release. Then it works perfectly.

Comment: Or just use ReentrantLock which is more intuitive.  lock() and unlock() do exactly what you think they do.